# Parse JSON without plugins

Tags: c#, json

So i have some Json:

```
{
    "name": "Shadow Realm",
    "description": "A spooky Haloween inspired map",
    "map": {
      "version": 79,
      "color_palette": [
       {
          "r": 96,
          "g": 209,
          "b": 234,
          "a": 255
       },
       {
          "r": 255,
          "g": 55,
          "b": 55,
          "a": 255
       }]
    }
}
```

And i am am able to read the first few values however i am not able to read the version and i am not sure what i should be reading the map entry as, any ideas?
I would prefer not to have to use a plugin as i wish to keep the project as small as possible if its do-able.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[System.Serializable]
public class Tests : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string jsonMapData;

    void Start()
    {
        jsonMapData = Import_bnl_bin.LoadResourceTextfile("map.json");
        MyClass jsonMap = new MyClass();
        jsonMap = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClass>(jsonMapData);

        Debug.Log("Name " + jsonMap.name + " : Desc " + jsonMap.description + " : Version " + jsonMap.version);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string name;
        public string description;

        public int version;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're worried about project size, might I suggest [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) or [MiniJSON](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the classes needed to be serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class Map
{
    public int version;
    public List<ColorPalette> color_palette;
}
```

otherwise it fails to read the data, also i ended up removing the

```
{ get; set; }
```

as it was overriding the

```
.FromJson()
```

funtion and causing it to return null

Answer (score 1):

Use http://json2csharp.com I generated the following classes using your sample JSON document.

```
public class ColorPalette
{
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int g { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int a { get; set; }
}

public class Map
{
    public int version { get; set; }
    public List<ColorPalette> color_palette { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Map map { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not familiar with `JsonUtility` but my guess would be that you would replace this line:

```
jsonMap = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClass>(jsonMapData);
```

With this:

```
jsonMap = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonMapData);
```

Or you could rename `RootObject` to `MyClass`.

Comment: ok so a class within a class that makes sense, however for some reason `Debug.log()` is unable to access this
`public string name { get; set; }`
the same way it would this
`public string name;`

Either i am accessing it wrong or data isn't storing correctly

Comment: Also `Debug.log(jsonMap.map.version)` throws a null reference exception.

Comment: Like I said, not familiar with `JsonUtility` so perhaps there's a bug in it that doesn't handle classes within classes. This parses perfectly using JSON.NET so it's valid JSON (assuming what you posted is exactly what you're using). I'm assuming `JsonUtility` is part of Unity3d, but don't feel like downloading and installing the whole thing to try it out myself.